# Java 8 stream for-loop

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

Im new to Java 8 Streams and would like to convert following code-block to Java 8's Stream way of doing the same thing.

**Edit**: Updates the class-names to be less confusing. (Removed Foo, Bar, Baz...)

```
ArrayList<PriceList> priceLists = new ArrayList<PriceList>();

// I'm casting to a type-safe List from getObjects() 
// -which is a function I dont have access to. Is there a nice 
// solution to embed this in the stream-syntax?
List<PriceListGroup> distObjects = (List<PriceListGroup>) objects.get(1).getObjects();

for(PriceListGroup group : distObjects) {
    Set<Affiliate> affiliates = group.getAffiliates();
    for(Affiliate affiliate : affiliates) {
        priceLists.add(affiliate.getPriceList());
    }
}
```

All help & explanation appreciated

Comment: Why did you include `objects.get(1).getObjects()` in your code example? Don't bother to reference things that you don't explain or provide in your example. It's best to create *new* code for us, which compiles and shows us how you used to work in pre-lambda days.

Comment: @Duncan I added that line to show that I must cast the return from getObjects() to a parameterized custom-classed List

Comment: Surely the construction of the lists is outside the scope of the question? I'm assuming the for-loop is all you care about.

Comment: @Duncan No what I care about is getting the excact same return type of my list of objects, that I currently have with my old for-loop. I want it to be type-safe. I dont want the Stream to return a `List<Object>`

Comment: I think you are missing my point. A great piece of example code is self-contained and has the minimal code necessary to demo the problem. See here for an example of what I would have created if I were you: https://gist.github.com/dmjones500/80fbd70d4bb0fd29cdcf. People can easily see your desired results and play around with their solution on the same data.

Comment: No I got you the first time @Duncan. However, could you please consider this: Lets say I would have written the question the way you suggest. Any answers to that question would still have left me uncertain of wether I should cast my `List<Object>` to a new `List<BarBO>` or (remember that I am new to Java 8) if there is a way to do this within the stream syntax. I would've then be forced to ask a new question here on stackexchange on this matter. To avoid spamming, why isn't it better to ask the question the way I like to see the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it with `flatMap` :

```
List<FooBO> list1 = objects.get(1).getObjects().stream()
                                  .flatMap (b -> b.getAffiliates().stream())
                                  .map(BazBo::getPriceList)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Edit :

Since `objects.get(1).getObjects()` seems to return a `List<Object>`, a cast is required. To be safe, you can also add a filter that makes sure the type of the `Object`s is indeed `BarBO` prior to the cast :

```
List<FooBO> list1 = objects.get(1).getObjects().stream()
                                  .filter (o -> (o instanceof BarBo))
                                  .map (o -> (BarBO)o)
                                  .flatMap (b -> b.getAffiliates().stream())
                                  .map(BazBo::getPriceList)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT :

Here's an answer with the class names of the edited question:

```
List<PriceList> priceLists = 
    distObjects.stream()
               .flatMap (g -> g.getAffiliates().stream())
               .map(Affiliate::getPriceList)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I get multiple markers with this example:
Row 1: Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to ArrayList<FooBo>
Row2: The method getAffiliates() is undefined for the type ?

Comment: @henrik Sorry about that. Replace `ArrayList` with `List` (see edit)

Comment: Now the first error went away, but still have this error: "The method getAffiliates() is undefined for the type ?" Thanks

Comment: @henrik I noticed that you cast `objects.get(1).getObjects()` to `List<BarBO>`. Can't you change `objects.get(1).getObjects()` to return `List<BarBO>` in the first place? If not, you can add this after `.stream()` : `.map(o -> (BarBO)o)`.

Comment: No I cant change that, it's not code that is accessible. I have to cast. there are 2 places where `.stream()` is. After which should i add `.map(o -> (BarBO)o)` ?

Comment: @henrik the first one

Comment: @Eran I would personally consider obtaining the list to be outside the scope of the question. In which case, your first answer looks great (with `someList` substituted for `objects.get(1).getObjects()`.

Comment: I still get errors in both examples provided.
In the edited example I get: "The method getAffiliates() is undefined for the type BarBO"

Comment: @henrik In your original code in the question you call `object.getAffiliates()` for `object` of type `BarBO`. I could only assume that your code passed compilation.

Comment: @henrik I just noticed I missed the call to `getPriceList`. See edited answer.

Comment: Confusing as hell. Unless some sort of parallelism is needed here, I'd go with procedural stuff, as in the question.

Comment: You can also use `.filter (BarBo.class::instanceof).map (BarBO::cast)` but it still looks like unnecessary operation dissolving to me. Just using `.stream().flatMap (b -> ((BarBo)b).getAffiliates().stream())` or, if you want to filter, `.stream().flatMap (b -> b instanceof BarBo? ((BarBo)b).getAffiliates().stream(): Stream.empty())` may be easier…

Comment: Both of the edited answers give me multiple errors with undefined functions and types. I've now updated the question to be less confusing.. Removed Foo, Bar, Baz, etc... Maybe its more clear now

Comment: @henrik see edited answer. If you are still getting errors, please write the exact error you are getting.

Comment: With your first answer:
"The method getAffiliates() is undefined for the type ?"
and
"The type BazBo does not define getPriceList(Object) that is applicable here"

Comment: @henrik What about the updated answer (the last answer)?

Comment: The last answer:
"Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<PriceList> to ArrayList<PriceList>"

Comment: @Eran However, if I change `ArrayList<PriceList> priceLists = ...` to `List<PriceList> priceLists = ...` it works! Thank you for a nice working answer

Comment: @henrik yep, I keep making that mistake of copying the ArrayList from your question and not changing it to List. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Considering your classes (in the example that you provided and assuming it compiles at least), I don't really understand why flatMap two times would not work:

```
 List<BarBO> input = new ArrayList<>();

    List<FooBO> result = input.stream()
            .flatMap((BarBO token) -> {
                return token.getAffiliats().stream();
            })
            .flatMap((BazBO token) -> {
                return token.getPriceList().stream();
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Won't this flatten all the price lists into one big price list? In OP's question it looks like he wants to keep the price lists separate (`add`, not `addAll`)

Comment: @tobias_k it does not look like that to me, It seems that for all BarBO he is getting all the BazBO (affiliates) and from that all FooBO (all pricelists).

Comment: Sure, but the price lists remain as individual lists. With your second `flatMap` you would unpack/combine them into one list, or not? `FooBO` seems to be the class of the price list, not of the individual price list items.

Comment: God knows why the question used `FooBo`, `BadoBADO` etc. rather than useful names... Anyway, I think Eugene is right here, the goal is a list containing all the pricelists (which are `FooBO` objects).

Comment: I get so many errors with this suggested answer, It doesnt compile at all, I'm gonna make the classes in my question less confusing. And lets see if that helps you guys to grip the example better