# How to replace two loops using streams and remains elements in list that are same

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

```
Set <ShipperModel> shippers = baseSiteSerivce.getCurrentBaseSite().getStores().get(0).getShippers();        
final List<KeyValueStoreModel> kvList = keyValueStoreService.getKeyValueStoreModelListByCode(HERITAGEUNIT_DELIVERYINSTRUCTION_SHIPVIA);

for (ShipperModel shipperModel : shippers)
{
    for (KeyValueStoreModel keyValueStoreModel : kvList)
    {
        if(shipperModel.getCode().equals(keyValueStoreModel.getCode()))
        {
            // if codes are equals then it will remain in the kvList.
        }
    }
}
```

I have two lists of items and based on the shippers i want to filter kvlist 
I want to perform operation like `kvlist.remainAll(shipper(based on code))`, and want to convert these loops to stream code.

Comment: please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29342714/1530987)

Comment: can't you convert the ShipperModel to a set or map with the code in it?

Comment: @Zeromus no i can not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not ideal but it you can try to do something like:

```
List<KeyValueStoreModel> filtered = kvlist.stream().filter(
      kv -> shippers.stream().anyMatch(
               s -> s.getCode().equals(kv.getCode())
            )
      )
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So we get a `Stream` of kv elements, than we check if there is any corresponding element in shippers `Set` and finally we collect matching elements into a new `List`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify existing collection, it's better to use [`Collection.removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
kvList.removeIf(model -> shippers.stream().map(ShipperModel::getCode)
                                 .noneMatch(model.getCode()::equals));
```

Here we pass a condition: we remove only those elements which have no corresponding code in the `shippers`.

If you have many shippers, you may consider dumping their code to the intermediate set first:

```
Set<Code> shipperCodes = shippers.stream().map(ShipperModel::getCode)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());
kvList.removeIf(model -> !shipperCodes.contains(model.getCode()));
```

This way the cost of the algorithm drops from O(N*M) to O(N+M) where N and M are number of shippers and models respectively.